# Trackpad2 clicking feedback stops after 30 seconds from initial use of the day

Tags: trackpad

When I open my MBP at the morning, I can feel the clicks for around 30 seconds, and then it's still functioning but without the click feedback. kind of goes to silent clicking mode.

The built-in MBP trackpad works fine and I've another trackpad2 at the office that works great.

Tried:

1. Turn it on and off.
2. Connent with cable and without.
3. Removed from connected devices and re-add it.
4. Went through all the possible checkboxes on Trackpad + Accessibility settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a physical issue and not a software one meaning you’ll have to get it replaced.

The [haptic feedback](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/394243/119271) is basically created by a small electromagnet that creates a vibration. There’s really no “mechanical” device.  However, these components can fail from time to time.

The symptom that it works fine for a little while then quits after a few moments points to a bad connection somewhere (like a  [dry solder joint](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/constructional_techniques/soldering/solder-joints.php)) that when things “warm up,” it fails.

The fact that the trackpad on your MBP works fine pretty much guarantees it’s not a software issue. Unfortunately that means you’ve got to replace it, but I’ve got clients who simply ignored it and continued to use it without the haptic feedback. For them, it was the track pad built in to the MBP and they preferred to wait until something more “major” needed service like the keyboard or battery to replace it.