# Trackpad not clicking on MacBook Air 2019

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, click

A few days ago, I opened my laptop after a night of sleep just to see my trackpad stopped clicking. Almost like the trackpad is stuck and that it won't make that clicking sound when you press onto the trackpad. Regardless, I can still click as in drag and drop. The only problem is that my trackpad wont physical click. My trackpad was working fine for the last couple of months since I bought the MacBook, but it just randomly stopped working for me.

A day later this issue, my trackpad randomly started clicking again. I simply can't fiqure out why this is the case. Then frustratingly, the day later the click was fixed, my trackpad click stopped working again. I simply don't understand, if this is a dust build-up issue or swollen battery. As of now, the trackpad is still stuck and just hoping for a miraculous fix for my trackpad.

Please, any response or explaination could help.

Comment: Also see this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/394243/119271. The issue is most likely a bad connection.  If it were your battery, the trackpad itself (the pad) would be deformed and it wouldn’t track properly or possibly even not work at all.

Comment: @Allan hello I have seen you answer and it seems like your suggesting I should take my laptop for servicing and change the almost everything in the top case; keyboard, battery, trackpad. Although I still have my warranty... it seems a bit hardcore, for the haptic feedback to just stop working randomly. Like if something in that system has failed then it shouldn't have returned to normal in the first place, right? And that's exactly what it did for me...

Comment: Not suggesting that... I’m saying that’s what’s *required* and it’s due to the design.  You have to disassemble/replace all of that to replace the track pad.  If it’s under warrant, I’d get it done.  To be candid, I’d wait until just before the warranty term expires because you’ll get a new battery eith the service.   As for “how” it failed, in both links, 
I mention “dry solder joints” that are flaky connections.  It will work one moment and fail the next.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the insight. Unfortunately, I will be leaving my country for university this September so I don't think I will be able to get this replaced just before my warranty expires, which is in November. So I probably have to sent the laptop in by this month. Do you happen to know how long it might take to replace and get my laptop fixed? Also, btw...if my shop does replace my keyboard do you think it's possible to request them to replace my butterfly keyboard to a magic keyboard, or will it cost me money?

Comment: It could take a day to a week - unfortunately I can only guess.  It all depends on your place in the repair queue and how many replacement parts they have on hand.  Just to make sure we're on the same page...you don't have to take it back to the *same* Apple store where you got it.  They will warranty it at a different store.

Comment: Oh, yea my country doesn't have an apple store. We have a centre who is an authorized reseller

Comment: Got it.  I understand now

Comment: also, I was wondering. Since they will be replacing my keyboard do u think it's possible to ask them to replace my butterfly to magic? Ofc with extra payment...

Comment: Technically, I can't answer for Apple (they have to speak for themselves), but I do know that the keyboards are different "enough" that you can't put the new Magic keyboards on MacBooks that came with the scissor mechanisms.

Comment: No worries...if the answers helped you out, please up vote!  Thanks!